# How to remove country field from My Account address?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-address

I tried,

For time being I am working on vendor folder later I will override custom module.

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml
```

I removed country field from phtml file. It got removed from form but while saving I am getting **countryId** is required field error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jassi,Country field is mandatory field in Magento. It is best idea to you should show country.

I guess,you site is only doing business on single country That why you want to country field.

### Best Idea:

Goto **Admin>Store>Configuration>General>Country Options** select Default as your country and Allow Countries as only your country.

***That will remove all country exclude Your countr list from Country list at fronted and  your country will be select default select country in drop***

*If  you will  want remove that then just using CSS make it display none.*

Comment: yes, in div I added style="display:none" but still it is visible in form

Comment: I guess  that  you did  not flush the cache